# Populate all rows of a column with same value

Tags: sql, postgresql

The issue is that I have a PostgreSQL table 'currency' with 4 columns: 'id', 'symbol', 'name', 'quote_asset'. The table contains 225 rows and column 'quote_asset' has all the values set to 'null' for now (it wasn't populated). Now I need to populate all the rows with the same value 'USDT'.
I tried the following query:

```
INSERT INTO currency (quote_asset) VALUES ('USDT');
```

It throws the following error:

> ERROR:  null value in column "symbol" violates not-null constraint
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (227, null, null, USDT). SQL state:
> 23502

I'm really not an expert of SQL, so, maybe someone could suggest a query that would work fine? I believe, it shouldn't be very difficult, but this basic thing that I was able to come up with didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `update`;

```
update currency 
    set quote_asset =  'USDT';
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much. I'll mark your answer as soon as the system allows me. :)